# How can I combine 3 different select statements from the same table:

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to obtain the count of columns for 3 categories of data types (numeric, non-numeric, date), grouped by table. To do so, I am querying the information schema on Snowflake.
At the moment, I am running 3 separate queries to obtain the result:

1. return count of numeric columns

```
select table_name, count(data_type)
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type in ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT')
group by table_name;
```

2. return count of non-numeric columns

```
select table_name, count(data_type)
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type in ('TEXT', 'VARIANT')
group by table_name;
```

3. return count of date columns

```
select table_name, count(data_type)
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type in ('TIMESTAMP', 'DATE')
group by table_name;
```

What is the best way to return the three result sets using one query? Ideally the output would be:

```
TABLE_NAME | COUNT OF NUMERIC COLUMNS | COUNT OF NON-NUMERIC COLUMNS | COUNT OF DATE COLUMNS
```

I've tried using UNION and UNION ALL but the statement only returns the numeric column count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try going with conditional aggregation. It should allow you to avoid the pivot operation.

```
SELECT table_name, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN data_type IN ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT') THEN 1 END),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN data_type IN ('TEXT', 'VARIANT') THEN 1 END),
       COUNT(CASE WHEN data_type IN ('TIMESTAMP', 'DATE') THEN 1 END)
FROM information_schema.columns 
GROUP BY table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you will need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.table_name,t2.table_name,t3.table_name),
ISNULL(t1.count_number,0) as "COUNT OF NUMERIC COLUMNS"
, ISNULL(t2.count_text,0) as "COUNT OF NON-NUMERIC COLUMNS"
, ISNULL(t3.count_date,0) As "COUNT OF DATE COLUMNS"
FROM
(select table_name, count(data_type) count_number
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type in ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT')
group by table_name) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select table_name, count(data_type) count_text
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type in ('TEXT', 'VARIANT')
group by table_name) t2 ON t1.table_name = t2.table_name
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(select table_name, count(data_type) count_date
from information_schema.columns 
where data_type in ('TIMESTAMP', 'DATE')
group by table_name) t3 ON ISNULL(t1..table_name, t2.table_name) = C.table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional count - [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if):

```
SELECT table_name, 
       COUNT_IF(data_type IN ('NUMBER', 'FLOAT'))   AS COUNT_NUMERIC_COLS,
       COUNT_IF(data_type IN ('TEXT', 'VARIANT'))   AS COUNT_TEXT_COLS,
       COUNT_IF(data_type IN ('TIMESTAMP', 'DATE')) AS COUNT_DATE_COLS
FROM information_schema.columns 
GROUP BY table_name;
```